# error in android studio with new project

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create a new project this message appears:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class Xmx512m
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

I try to change the gradle and compiler setting to `Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reset your android studio by closing android studio and removing the following directories.

~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioBeta

~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta

~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioBeta

~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta"

Then restart android studio.

Answer (score 0):

just create new environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and give it the value `-Xms256m -Xmx1024m`